# Python check attribute type in inherited abstract class

Tags: python, abstract-class

I have a basic abstract class structure such as the following:

```py
from abc import ABCMeta, abstractmethod

class BaseClass(metaclass=ABCMeta):
   @property
   @abstractmethod
   def class_name(self):
       pass

   @property
   @abstractmethod
   def class_val(self):
       pass

   @abstractmethod
   def foo(self):
       pass

   def bar(self):
       # do something


class ChildClass1(BaseClass):
    class_name = "Child1"
    class_val = 1

    def foo(self):
        # do something else


class ChildClass2(BaseClass):
    class_name = "Child2"
    class_val = 2

    def foo(self):
        # do something else again
```

This works to basically do what I want, i.e., it lets me define variations of a base class which share the same implementation of the method `bar()` but have different implementations of `foo()`, with different class-specific attributes -- all of which *must* be implemented in the child classes, otherwise it raises the error `TypeError: Can't instantiate abstract class ChildClass1 with abstract methods class_name` (for example, if I try implement it without the `class_name` class attribute).

This is almost what I want. However I would like to know if there is any way I can force the child classes to have a string type for the `class_name` attribute, an `int` type for the `class_val` attribute, etc.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best thing to do would be to **use type hints**, and then validate the type hints using a third party tool such as `mypy`:

```py
class BaseClass(metaclass=ABCMeta):
   @property
   @abstractmethod
   def class_name(self) -> str:
       pass

   @property
   @abstractmethod
   def class_val(self) -> int:
       pass

   @abstractmethod
   def foo(self):
       pass

   def bar(self):
       pass
```

If you try to define a subclass with the wrong types for the properties, `mypy` will throw an error, e.g. with:

```py
class ChildClass2(BaseClass):
    class_name = "Child2"
    class_val = "a"

    def foo(self):
        pass
```

you'd get the error along the lines of:

```
test.py: error: Incompatible types in assignment
(expression has type "str", base class "BaseClass" defined the type as "int")
```

This *technically* doesn't stop someone from defining a subclass that has the wrong type, since the Python runtime ignores type hints. However, an approach that raises an error if a bad type is encountered would likely need a call to `isinstance()` for each instance variable, which would become unwieldy if you have a lot of properties that you want to enforce the types for.